# Authenticate command line utility with active directory

Tags: active-directory, azure-active-directory, command-line-interface

I have to write command line utility (executes on windows machine) to upload files to Azure cloud from given local path. However, that action should be allowed only for certain set of active directory users/roles. 
Then, utility should exchange token with Azure Active Directory, and upload files to Azure Cloud.

So, only authenticated and authorized users (through active directory) on local network should do it. Also those users has to be authenticated on Azure Active Directory. On AZ Cloud users are replicated (same users, same AD credentials and permissions).

What would be the best approach to do it? Or should I abandon that approach and write small desktop app?
Web app is not option in this case as files must be "pushed" to the API on the cloud.

Comment: May I know if my answer helps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure storage supports authentication with Azure AD access token. For more details, you may refer to [Authorize access to blobs and queues using Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad) and [Authorize with Azure AD credentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/authorize-data-operations-cli?toc=%2fazure%2fstorage%2fblobs%2ftoc.json#authorize-with-azure-ad-credentials).

You need to assign necessary roles to users:

- [Storage Blob Data Owner](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#storage-blob-data-owner): For POSIX access control for Azure Data Lake
  Storage Gen2.
- [Storage Blob Data Contributor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#storage-blob-data-contributor): Read/write/delete permissions for
  blobs.
- [Storage Blob Data Reader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#storage-blob-data-reader): Read-only permissions for blobs.

Then you can [log in to Azure Active Directory to access Azure Storage resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-ref-azcopy-login?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Ftoc.json).

If you want to manage Azure Storage with REST API, you may refer to [Use OAuth access tokens for authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-with-azure-active-directory)